# Windows azure active directory authentication in android?

Tags: android, authentication, azure, azure-active-directory

I have been checking around the web, and havent found a clear cut answer. What im trying to do is authenticate against windows azure active directory tenants in an android app. The authentication protocol isnt an issue, but i was thinking that saml 2.0 would be prefered.

*I have been able to do this in .net quite simply. so if the above is not possible, i was wondering if creating a web app using .net and the using this app in android to authenticate by detecting cookies.

*Note im quite new to authentication and android in general, so i would love any pointers u can give me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing. I found this website from Mircorsoft which has steps to add in authentication to your Android app.

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-android/

This link starts the intro to Mobile services for Android

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-android/